# Como utilizar array de Data no Highcharts?

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

Fiz essa simulação ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toa062cj/17/) também):

```js
$(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cqueInyKdK?indent=2",
    type: 'POST'
  }).done(function(makeTheDO) {

    console.log(makeTheDO);
    //datas que quero no eixo X
    console.log(makeTheDO[0].data);
    //series que quero no eixo Y
    console.log(makeTheDO[0].serie);

    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
      },

      yAxis: {
        category: makeTheDO[0].data
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'ponto no periodo da data que nao consigo por',
        data: makeTheDO[0].serie,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 1
        }
      }]
    });




  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<h3>Como usar datas do BD em um json no highcharts Eixo X?</h3>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

Mas esse json está sendo montado no meu banco de dados através do **PHP**, essa data vem do banco de dados, e não estou conseguindo colocar ela no eixoX, alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: não tava funcionando porque não tem como colocar HTTP dentro de um site HTTPS sem afetar a segurança, mudei o link `http://www.json-generator.com/api/` para `https://www.json-generator.com/api/` (ou seja mudei para HTTPS)

Comment: Tentou `xAxis`? Não sei se entendi o seu problema

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no meu código eu tentei category: makeTheDO[0].data, para no eixo xAxis ele colocar 1 de Jan.. etc, mas não aparece no eixo x, como vc pode ver na img do grafico

Comment: Teu JSON esta em formato errado ao ser passado para os eixos, veja os exemplos https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes